# jQuery-UI Draggable doesn't work in IE 8 but works in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm using jquery ui for the draggable part. #photo is the element which should be draggable. It works fine on Chrome and firefox, and the page doesn't throw any errors on IE8. However when I try to drag the #photo on IE8 it doesn't work. 
There are 2 elements which make the final round image: 1. The actual rectangular blue photo. and 2. A mask with a circular hole which sits atop the image.
Now in Chrome if I right click on top and select 'open image in new tab' the blue photo opens up. However in IE, if I try to do the same I get the mask with a circular hole. 
To sum up, he draggable is working, but the mask is being accessed in IE instead of the photo.

Here is the page where it isn't working on IE8: http://bit.ly/zVPMvZ

Comment: I found a simple solution here :D
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313171/is-it-possible-to-have-a-jquery-draggable-object-under-an-other-div
the trick is to pass the mouse down events to the photo div under the mask.

`$('#mask').mousedown(function(ev) {
    $('#photo').trigger(ev);
});  
`

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer and accept it if it answers your question :)

Comment: :) SO has banned me from answering... If any admin is reading this, pls do something about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#mytopdiv').mousedown(function(ev) {
    $('#bottomdiv').trigger(ev);
});
```